# Why is signal bad in a tunnel?

Tags: electromagnetism, everyday-life, radiation, dielectric, waveguide

Consider this:

you are driving through a tunnel listening to your AM radio and a GPS, all of the sudden AM radio has nothing but statics and your GPS says "reconnecting - please hold".

You say to yourself, this can't be happening, because radio signal would move through the opening of the tunnel to reach your antennas.

What are some of the factors causing this phenomenon?

Comment: Maybe you should read up on *Faraday cages*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is all about wavelength versus tunnel diameter. The wavelength of GPS is about 20cm it would happily propagate in any normal tunnel if it could get in but the earth and other structures absorb it. AM radio (600kHz - 1500kHz) cannot propagate in any normal tunnel because the wavelength is too long (500m-200m) relative to the diameter, and thus gets reflected at the entrance. FM (100MHz ~ 3m) would propagate and it does for a while but then it suffers reflections (multipath) inside and reception turns to crap.

Answer (score 3):

Both of these technologies rely on radio frequency waves, which are blocked by dense matter eg, a hill, a building.

Answer (score 2):

Radio waves are just light of a different frequency. Yes, they are slightly better at reflecting off various surfaces than light, but they still generally travel in straight lines. They don't flow or fill space like a fluid, so there is no reason to believe they'd be good at following you into a tunnel. You generally need line of sight (or something close to it) to the radio tower to get a signal. The same holds for GPS.